# \begin doesn't match its definition

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox

I tried to create a transparent box with text. So, I created a new color box called mybox.

```
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % just to avoid font size warnings

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    width=20cm,
    arc=3mm,
%    auto outer arc,
    boxsep=0cm,
    coltext = white,
    colback = black,
    toprule=0pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    fontupper=\centering\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\itshape,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    opacityframe=0.8,
    opacityback=0.8
}
```

Then I tried to insert the text as mentioned below. But I'm getting an error saying `\begin doesn't match its definition`. I couldn't find why. Can someone find the reason for it? Note: Inspite of that error, the box is created, but I am not able to make the text bold.

```
\title{
\begin{mybox}[]
 \textbf{Voltage Regulation on a High PV penetrated Distributed System using Electric Vehicles}
\end{mybox}
  }
```

Comment: make a complete example, that makes is much easier to test your issue.

Comment: This is in the title page of my report. I am not sure what to paste it here.

Comment: This code inside an article class works for me without any message except that the box is too wide.

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3350/2388